# how to login kubenetes dashboard pod in terminal

Tags: kubernetes

I am using Treafik ingress to forward request into kubernetes(v1.15.2) dashboard container,but it give me no page found error. now I want to login into kubernetes dashboard to try to get the home page html using this command:

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:8443
```

Now I am stuck in login into kubernetes dashboard container. I am using this command to login kubernetes dashboard:

```
kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/bash
```

and throw this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

and this is what I already tried:

```
[root@ops001 conf.d]# docker exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 /bin/ash
Error: No such container: kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 /bin/bash
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9" not found
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=kube-system
Context "kubernetes" modified.
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 /bin/bash
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 /bin/ash
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/ash\": stat /bin/ash: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/bash
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 --
error: you must specify at least one command for the container
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- ls
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/ls
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/ls\": stat /bin/ls: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/\": stat /bin/: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/\": permission denied": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/sh
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/ash
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/ash\": stat /bin/ash: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- /bin/bash
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]# kubectl exec -it kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9 -- env
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"env\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ops001 conf.d]#
```

what should I do to login the kubenetes dashboard container?

Comment: If your proxy doesn't work as expected you can debug it using docker image (as pod/container) https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to use `kubectl proxy` as it is independend if there are any ingresses or other network ressources available...it should work in any environment as long as kubectl has the correct context.

So try

```sh
kubectl proxy
```

Then use your browser to navigate to

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Be aware that this URL contains the namespace **kube-system** where the **kubernetes-dashboard** must be deployed in. Change the URL accordingly if it is deployed differently on your cluster.

Comment: kube proxy is the better way?I am already using this way now. next step I want to using treafik to access the kubernetes dashboard service.is it nessasory?@Jürgen Zornig

Comment: I don't think that it is necessery to use an ingress as you don't want your dashboard to be visible outside your cluster to anybody else than you.

Ingress is for defining rules how to route requests that reach your public service url to resources/services running inside your cluster