# why “kubectl exec -it” cannot login on google container optimised os

Tags: docker, kubectl, google-container-optimized-os

When i ran kubectl exec -it  /bin/bash, i got error like this

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"env\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown command terminated with exit code 126`

i made several retries using kubectl and docker exec as but nothing works on google container optimized os

i used the following ones

- `kubectl exec -it <podname> /bin/bash`
- `kubectl exec -it <podname> /bin/sh`
- `kubectl exec -it <podname> //bin//sh`
- `kubectl exec -it <podname> //bin//bash`
- `kubectl exec -it <podname> /bash`
  `kubectl exec -it <podname> bash`

i logged into server and tried to login to docker container using `docker exec -it <containerId> <all options mentioned above>`. But nothing seems to worked out well.

Comment: Does the image for the container you're trying to exec into have any of these binaries/commands installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BMitch mentioned, your docker image must have bash or sh otherwise your command will fail with the exact same message.

I just ran a test, created a GKE cluster with Container-Optimized OS with Containerd (cos_containerd) and run the following:

```
kubectl run busybox --image busybox:1.28 --command sleep 1200
kubectl exec busybox -it -- sh
```

and successfully exec into the pod. This is not related to the OS container optimized, rather it might be related to your docker image.

Comment: As @CaioT mentioned,If the container image includes debugging utilities, you can run commands inside a specific container with [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#container-exec) command.You can run a shell that's connected to your terminal using the -i and -t arguments to kubectl exec`kubectl exec -i -t my-pod --container main-app -- /bin/bash`
The short options -i and -t are the same as the long options --stdin and --tty.The double dash (--) separates the arguments you want to pass to the command from the kubectl arguments.

Comment: Refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984490/how-to-login-kubenetes-dashboard-pod-in-terminal) for another work around for a similar error message